# Objective-C - Trying to play sound

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to play a sound in my app with the following code:

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"errorbeep.wav" ofType:@"m4a"];
        NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

        AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL
                                                                       error:nil];
        player.numberOfLoops = -1; //Infinite

        [player play];
```

But the sound does not play :(

after debugging, I can see that soundFilePath is nil Here is a screenshot of my Resources file:

[image]

Comment: wav.m4a ? is it a correct format? isnt it supposed to be wav or m4a ?

Comment: please correct the extension of your music file and check whether the file exists in Xcode -> Targets -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources

Comment: just advice: for short sounds is better to use SystemSounds library.

Answer (score 1):

You should import the file to your project with one extension. Thats probably what's going on. Just re-import the file as one extension (i.e, errorbeep.m4a)

Answer (score 0):

If the file path is nil I would try renaming the file to just errorbeep.m4a and then doing:

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"errorbeep" ofType:@"m4a"];
```

Comment: I tried renaming the file and it returned nil still

Answer (score 0):

Select your sound file and see if you have its Target Membership Checked for your target.

[image]